# Will mouse enhanced pointer precision affect my aim if I have mouse acceleration turned off in tf2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have the setting for mouse acceleration disabled in tf2, but I see a lot of guides recommending that I disable enhanced pointer precision in windows.

Are these two things different and do I need them both to be disabled or will the in game setting suffice?   I really like enhanced pointer precision when I'm not playing games so I don't want to disable this if it's possible.